# Distinguish between page and post in function

Tags: filters, post-thumbnails, post-type

I'm trying to apply some text to the "Featured Image" box. It works fine for a custom post type, but I can't get a specific piece of text appearing on pages rather than posts.

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'foo' );
function foo( $content ) {
    global $post_type;
    if ( $post_type = 'page') {
        $content = '<p>foobar</p>' . $content;
     }
    else{
        $content = '<p>barfoo</p>' . $content;
     }
     return $content;
}
```

How can I get WordPress to identify if it is just a page?

Comment: You're missing an `=` sign in the `if` statement.

Comment: I am indeed - thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

By using post id you can get post type of current post/page. try below code. i have tested and it is working fine for me.

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'foo',10,3 );
function foo( $content, $post_id, $thumbnail_id ) {
   if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'page' ) {
        $content = '<p>foobar</p>' . $content;
     }
    else{
        $content = '<p>barfoo</p>' . $content;
     }
     return $content;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks - as WebElaine said above, it was simply that I had a single = in my if statement - whereas you have ==

Comment: yes it can also do. from documentation of [admin_post_thumbnail_html](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_thumbnail_html) you can pass post id in argument and by using post id you can get post type.